# MySQL from decimal(13.6) to currency

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to get from an decimal(13.6) value to currency in EURO's

I'm getting this as result right now:

```
╔══════════════╦═════════╗
║   total      ║ Date    ║
╠══════════════╬═════════╣
║8887616.500000║ 2017    ║
╚══════════════╩═════════╝
```

What I want is something like this one:

```
╔══════════════╦═════════╗
║   total      ║ Date    ║
╠══════════════╬═════════╣
║€8,887.616.50 ║ 2017    ║
╚══════════════╩═════════╝
```

Or this one:

```
╔══════════════╦═════════╗
║   total      ║ Date    ║
╠══════════════╬═════════╣
║   €M8,9      ║ 2017    ║
╚══════════════╩═════════╝
```

I did try to convert from decimal but had no luck with that

```
SELECT  SUM(totalExcl) AS total, DATE_FORMAT(date_add, '%Y') AS 'Date'
FROM ex.ps_oxo_quotation
WHERE saleType IN ('IEW' , 'As', 'Pr')
AND date_add >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY 'Date'
ORDER BY 'Date' DESC
```

Comment: Which locale uses BOTH ',' AND '.' as thousands separators?

Comment: You can test with `SELECT FORMAT(8887616.500000, 2, 'locale');` and you own locale read about MySQL's function FORMAT here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format... Don't know of the FORMAT function will support your wierd locale that uses BOTH ',' AND '.' as separators.

Comment: FORMAT(8890905.860000, 2, 'de_DE'), this one changed to '8.890.905,86'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a sum formatted in Euro:

```
SELECT CONCAT('€', FORMAT(SUM(totalExcl), 2, 'de_DE')) AS total
```

Will show: `€8.890.905,86`

The other requested alternative:

```
SELECT CONCAT('€M', FORMAT((SUM(totalExcl)/1000000), 1, 'de_DE')) AS total
```

Will show: `€M8,9`

Note that this example will show the sum according to standards (LOCALE de_DE), and not with the exact format you have requested, that have mixed dots "." and commas "," in a non standard way. This could easily be fixed with some string manipulation if you really must format the sum that way.